# NameError: name 'utils' is not defined in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, torchvision, pytorch-dataloader

I have `pytorch 1.7`. The following code is same as from Pytorch's tutorial page for [Object detection and finetuning.](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html)

But I have error for the following line

```
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)
```

as `NameError: name 'utils' is not defined`

What could be wrong?

The whole code is as follows.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import torch
from PIL import Image


class PrepareDataset(object):
    def __init__(self, root, transforms):
        self.root = root
        self.transforms = transforms
        # load all image files, sorting them to
        # ensure that they are aligned
        self.imgs = list(sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(root, "images"))))
        self.masks = list(sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(root, "masks"))))
        self.annotations = list(sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(root, "annotations"))))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # load images ad masks
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root, "images", self.imgs[idx])
        mask_path = os.path.join(self.root, "masks", self.masks[idx])
        annotation_path = os.path.join(self.root, "annotations", self.annotations[idx])
        img = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")
        # note that we haven't converted the mask to RGB,
        # because each color corresponds to a different instance
        # with 0 being background
        mask = Image.open(mask_path)
        # convert the PIL Image into a numpy array
        mask = np.array(mask)
        # instances are encoded as different colors
        obj_ids = np.unique(mask)
        # first id is the background, so remove it
        obj_ids = obj_ids[1:]

        # split the color-encoded mask into a set
        # of binary masks
        masks = mask == obj_ids[:, None, None]

        # get bounding box coordinates for each mask
        num_objs = len(obj_ids)
        boxes = []
        for i in range(num_objs):
            pos = np.where(masks[i])
            xmin = np.min(pos[1])
            xmax = np.max(pos[1])
            ymin = np.min(pos[0])
            ymax = np.max(pos[0])
            boxes.append([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])

        # convert everything into a torch.Tensor
        boxes = torch.as_tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32)
        # there is only one class
        labels = torch.ones((num_objs,), dtype=torch.int64)
        masks = torch.as_tensor(masks, dtype=torch.uint8)

        image_id = torch.tensor([idx])
        area = (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1]) * (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0])
        # suppose all instances are not crowd
        iscrowd = torch.zeros((num_objs,), dtype=torch.int64)

        target = {}
        target["boxes"] = boxes
        target["labels"] = labels
        target["masks"] = masks
        target["image_id"] = image_id
        target["area"] = area
        target["iscrowd"] = iscrowd

        if self.transforms is not None:
            img, target = self.transforms(img, target)

        return img, target

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.imgs)
    
    
import torchvision
from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FastRCNNPredictor

# load a model pre-trained pre-trained on COCO
model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)

# replace the classifier with a new one, that has
# num_classes which is user-defined
num_classes = 2  # 1 class (person) + background
# get number of input features for the classifier
in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
# replace the pre-trained head with a new one
model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)


import torchvision
from torchvision.models.detection import FasterRCNN
from torchvision.models.detection.rpn import AnchorGenerator

# load a pre-trained model for classification and return
# only the features
backbone = torchvision.models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained=True).features
# FasterRCNN needs to know the number of
# output channels in a backbone. For mobilenet_v2, it's 1280
# so we need to add it here
backbone.out_channels = 1280

# let's make the RPN generate 5 x 3 anchors per spatial
# location, with 5 different sizes and 3 different aspect
# ratios. We have a Tuple[Tuple[int]] because each feature
# map could potentially have different sizes and
# aspect ratios
anchor_generator = AnchorGenerator(sizes=((32, 64, 128, 256, 512),), aspect_ratios=((0.5, 1.0, 2.0),))

# let's define what are the feature maps that we will
# use to perform the region of interest cropping, as well as
# the size of the crop after rescaling.
# if your backbone returns a Tensor, featmap_names is expected to
# be [0]. More generally, the backbone should return an
# OrderedDict[Tensor], and in featmap_names you can choose which
# feature maps to use.
roi_pooler = torchvision.ops.MultiScaleRoIAlign(featmap_names=[0], output_size=7, sampling_ratio=2)

# put the pieces together inside a FasterRCNN model
model = FasterRCNN(backbone, num_classes=5, rpn_anchor_generator=anchor_generator, box_roi_pool=roi_pooler)


import torchvision
from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FastRCNNPredictor
from torchvision.models.detection.mask_rcnn import MaskRCNNPredictor


def get_model_instance_segmentation(num_classes):
    # load an instance segmentation model pre-trained pre-trained on COCO
    model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)

    # get number of input features for the classifier
    in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
    # replace the pre-trained head with a new one
    model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)

    # now get the number of input features for the mask classifier
    in_features_mask = model.roi_heads.mask_predictor.conv5_mask.in_channels
    hidden_layer = 256
    # and replace the mask predictor with a new one
    model.roi_heads.mask_predictor = MaskRCNNPredictor(in_features_mask,
                                                       hidden_layer,
                                                       num_classes)

    return model


from torchvision import transforms as T


def get_transform(train):
    transforms = []
    transforms.append(T.ToTensor())
    if train:
        transforms.append(T.RandomHorizontalFlip(0.5))
    return T.Compose(transforms)


model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
dataset = PrepareDataset('/home/centos/atic-nyan/Traffic', get_transform(train=True))
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)
# For Training
images,targets = next(iter(data_loader))
images = list(image for image in images)
targets = [{k: v for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]
output = model(images,targets)   # Returns losses and detections
# For inference
model.eval()
x = [torch.rand(3, 300, 400), torch.rand(3, 500, 400)]
predictions = model(x)           # Returns predictions



from engine import train_one_epoch, evaluate
import utils


def main():
    # train on the GPU or on the CPU, if a GPU is not available
    device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')

    # our dataset has two classes only - background and person
    num_classes = 2
    # use our dataset and defined transformations
    dataset = PrepareDataset('/home/centos/atic-nyan/Traffic', get_transform(train=True))
    dataset_test = PrepareDataset('/home/centos/atic-nyan/Traffic', get_transform(train=False))

    # split the dataset in train and test set
    indices = torch.randperm(len(dataset)).tolist()
    dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, indices[:-50])
    dataset_test = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset_test, indices[-50:])

    # define training and validation data loaders
    data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, num_workers=4,
        collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)

    data_loader_test = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset_test, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=4,
        collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)

    # get the model using our helper function
    model = get_model_instance_segmentation(num_classes)

    # move model to the right device
    model.to(device)

    # construct an optimizer
    params = [p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=0.005,
                                momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)
    # and a learning rate scheduler
    lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer,
                                                   step_size=3,
                                                   gamma=0.1)

    # let's train it for 10 epochs
    num_epochs = 10

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # train for one epoch, printing every 10 iterations
        train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
        # update the learning rate
        lr_scheduler.step()
        # evaluate on the test dataset
        evaluate(model, data_loader_test, device=device)

    print("That's it!")
```

Comment: Did you install pytorch correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I just put

```
def collate_fn(batch):
    data_list, label_list = [], []
    for _data, _label in batch:
        data_list.append(_data)
        label_list.append(_label)
    return torch.Tensor(data_list), torch.LongTensor(label_list)
```

in my code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

change this `data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)`
to
`data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, collate_fn=torch.utils.collate_fn)`

Since your collate function uses collate module

Answer (score 0):

copy this `https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/references/detection/transforms.py`
`https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/references/detection/utils.py`
to your project.
remember rename files

Answer (score -2):

There is discussion on discuss.pytorch about this tutorial. https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/object-detection-finetuning-tutorial/52651
You can find in tutorial:

> In references/detection/ , we have a number of helper functions to simplify training and evaluating detection models. Here, we will use references/detection/engine.py , references/detection/utils.py and references/detection/transforms.py . Just copy them to your folder and use them here.

There are this files in this page https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/master/references/detection
Also you should install pycocotools.